# Changing font type and size of nomenclature

Tags: fonts, pdftex, elsarticle, nomencl, els-cas

I am preparing a manuscript using Elsevier `cas-dc.cls` class. In that I have added a nomenclature using package `nomencl`. While I would like the font type and size to be the same as the rest of the document, these are different for the nomenclature. Using `\expandafter\show\the\font`, I have figured out that the font type and size used by the rest of the document are `T1/stix/m/n/10` while for the nomenclature, these are `T1/cmss/m/n/9`.

I am looking for a way to set the font type and size of the nomenclature to the same as those used by the rest of the document. I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more search and reading, I found a solution. Simply adding `\fontfamily{stix}\selectfont` before `\printnomenclature` did it for me. However, the font size was 9pt. So, I also added `\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont`. So, in short, use the following:

```
\fontfamily{stix}\selectfont
\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
\printnomenclature
```